# If $X$ is integrable then $\mathbb{E}[\sqrt{a_0 + a_1X^2}]$ is finite

Tags: probability-theory, inequality

Let $X$ be an integrable random variable with possibly no moment of order 2.

Let $a_0$ and $a_1$ be two positive scalars. I want to prove that $\mathbb{E}[\sqrt{a_0 + a_1X^2}] < \infty$

I tried to use Jensen or $\sqrt{x} < 1 + x$, but to do that I have to assume that $\mathbb{E}[X^2] < \infty$ which is not the case.

Comment: Hint: Prove the pointwise inequality $$\sqrt{a_0+a_1X^2}\leqslant\sqrt{a_0}+\sqrt{a_1}\,|X|$$ and integrate it.

Comment: 7 minutes. $ $ $ $

Comment: Thanks, I proved $\sqrt{a+x} \leq \sqrt{a} + \sqrt{x}$ with $a \geq 0$ and $x \geq 0$ and it works

Comment: Exactly. $ $ $ $